# Grails Domain Classes Dates

Tags: grails, date, grails-domain-class

I have this domain class:

```
class activity {

    String name
    Date startDate
    Date endDate


    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

What i want to do is:

a) apply constrains to the dates, for example minimum date and maximum date

b) in my project i need to have an Array of dates and add as many endDates as i want. is it possible to do so? and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good reading of the Grails docs would answer a lot of the questions you've been asking here.

a) [Adding Custom Validation to a Field](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html)

b) If I understand you correctly, what you might want to do is create another class called something like ActivityEndDate and then build your domain like this:

```
class Activity {

   // regular properties

   static hasMany = [endDates:ActivityEndDate]   

}
```

Again, the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html) are helpful here.

Comment: thx for the answer. Could you give me an example of validator using dates? because, im not really sure how to use it, dates are a bit complex to manage.

Comment: Dates in groovy are easy.  I'd prefer not to write your code for you.  Work something out and when you get stuck, ask a new question and include your code. http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN0545-Dates

Answer (score 2):

> a) apply constrains to the dates, for example minimum date and maximum date

Here's an example of a minimum and maximum constraint applied to the `startDate` field

```
class activity {

    String name
    Date startDate
    Date endDate

    static constraints = {

        // date must be between today and today + 7 days
        startDate(min: new Date(), max: newDate() + 7)
    }
}
```